# What should I add to my dependencies to make a toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to delete actionbar and replace with a toolbar but i don't know what to put to my dependencies!
Here is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.helloword"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: You don't need extra dependency for `toolbar` as you have `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`

Comment: Toolbar is part of androidx (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this theme to your style:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/loginBackground</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

add this to your activity theme in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:theme="@style/MainTheme" />
```

Now you can add toolbar to your activity xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

now finally add it to your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add any dependecis for showing toolbar.If you want to add custom toolbar in your project, go to style.xml file and make the style parent **NoActionBar** instead of **DarkActionBar**.

After that,just add those codes in your xml file.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Find it from your Activity file

```
    private Toolbar toolbar;  // first declare it in your Activity class
```

Then find it and set it to your **OnCreate** method

```
    toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title here");  // If you want to add Title
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any dependencies to do that, start using it by adding

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" />
```

to your layout